# Swift: Interoperability of UnsafeMutablePointer.deallocate(capacity:) with free()

Tags: c, swift, interop

Can I use `UnsafeMutablePointer.deallocate(capacity:)` with a pointer whose memory has previously been allocated using `malloc`? I.e., does `deallocate` behave like `free`?

One scenario where this happens is when calling C functions from Swift which allocate memory using `malloc` and expect the caller to `free()` that memory later. An example is the `LIBMTP_Detect_Raw_Devices` function ([see here for an example use](https://github.com/libmtp/libmtp/blob/master/examples/files.c)). The function expects that the caller frees the memory (`rawdevices`) allocated inside the function.

Comment: Good question, but can't you just call `free()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is unclear about this, but testing suggests interoperability.

Using `malloc()` in C, then calling `deallocate()` in Swift and trying to `free()` the pointer in C (or vice versa) will result in a run-time error, yet the code will run fine if only one of `deallocate()` or `free()` is used, but not both.

Similarly, allocating a structure in Swift, then using `deallocate()` in Swift and `free()` in C (or the other way around) will also result in a run-time error.

It is also OK to use `free()` in Swift as suggested by @jtbandes.  In fact, this approach might be safer than calling `deallocate()`.

As for documentation, see https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablepointer.

Also, you can dig through the `UnsafeMutablePointer`'s source code here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/UnsafePointer.swift.gyb

I haven't had time to figure out the implementation yet.